# Bluetooth programming in C

Tags: android, c, bluetooth

I managed to successfully connect two android phones using apps i made and I tried to use what I learned there to connect an android phone to my raspberry pi( which uses Raspbian Jessie ). I tried to implement the server side on the raspberry and use the client version of my android app. But i noticed something was missing in the code this gentleman wrote: http://people.csail.mit.edu/albert/bluez-intro/x502.html

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <bluetooth/bluetooth.h>
#include <bluetooth/rfcomm.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct sockaddr_rc loc_addr = { 0 }, rem_addr = { 0 };
    char buf[1024] = { 0 };
    int s, client, bytes_read;
    socklen_t opt = sizeof(rem_addr);

    // allocate socket
    s = socket(AF_BLUETOOTH, SOCK_STREAM, BTPROTO_RFCOMM);

    // bind socket to port 1 of the first available 
    // local bluetooth adapter
    loc_addr.rc_family = AF_BLUETOOTH;
    loc_addr.rc_bdaddr = *BDADDR_ANY;
    loc_addr.rc_channel = (uint8_t) 1;
    bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&loc_addr, sizeof(loc_addr));

    // put socket into listening mode
    listen(s, 1);

    // accept one connection
    client = accept(s, (struct sockaddr *)&rem_addr, &opt);

    ba2str( &rem_addr.rc_bdaddr, buf );
    fprintf(stderr, "accepted connection from %s\n", buf);
    memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));

    // read data from the client
    bytes_read = read(client, buf, sizeof(buf));
    if( bytes_read > 0 ) {
        printf("received [%s]\n", buf);
    }

    // close connection
    close(client);
    close(s);
    return 0;
}
```

In android I had to hard code a UUID into both the server and the client side but here I see no reference to anything that might be a UUID. Why is that?

This is the android code:
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        System.exit(1);
    }

    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
    Object[] pairedDev = pairedDevices.toArray();
    ArrayAdapter<String> mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 0);
    /*if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
        for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
            mArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
        }
    }
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.PairedDevicesListView);
    listView.setAdapter(mArrayAdapter);*/
    ConnectThread connectThread = new ConnectThread((BluetoothDevice) pairedDev[1]);
    connectThread.run();
    connectThread.cancel();
}

public void buttonOnClick(View v)
{
    Button button = (Button) v;

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
}


private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
        mmDevice = device;

        try {
            tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.fromString("F4C20AC0-3DF8-11E6-BDF4-0800200C9A66"));
        } catch (IOException e) { }
        mmSocket = tmp;
    }

    public void run() {
        BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        try {
            mmSocket.connect();
        } catch (IOException connectException) {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
                System.exit(1);
            } catch (IOException closeException) { System.exit(1); }
            return;
        }

        // Do work to manage the connection (in a separate thread)
        // manageConnectedSocket(mmSocket);
        byte[] bytes = new byte[3];
        bytes[0] = 1;
        bytes[1] = 3;
        bytes[2] = 2;
        ConnectedThread connectedThread = new ConnectedThread(mmSocket);
        connectedThread.write(bytes);
    }

    /** Will cancel an in-progress connection, and close the socket */
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }
}

private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

    public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        mmSocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        // Get the input and output streams, using temp objects because
        // member streams are final
        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) { }

        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    }

    public void run() {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  // buffer store for the stream
        int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

        // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
        while (true) {
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream
                bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity
                // mHandler.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /* Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device */
    public void write(byte[] bytes) {
        try {
            mmOutStream.write(bytes);
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }

    /* Call this from the main activity to shutdown the connection */
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing that either the `socket` call or the `bind` call take care of that behind the scenes. You should really ask this question with the android tag, and your android code.

Comment: I will post the android code as well.